# How to call @role('admin') inside the HTML in Laravel Breeze React with Spatie/laravel-permissions

Tags: reactjs, laravel-permission, laravel-breeze

I want to create a admin dashboard with Laravel Breeze (React) and using the Spatie/laravel-permissions, I created a new project with Laravel Breeze (React) and install the Spatie/laravel-permissions.

I also assigned the role to the current user in my Database Seeder, but now how to hide the specific button in different admin roles?

I do some research about that, they using @role('admin') and @endrole, but i have error tag in my react components, here's my react components code:

```
@role('admin')
    <button>Edit</button>
@endrole
```

Please help me ~